# PHP PCRE error preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-match, pcre

```
<?php
    function pregForPreg($value)
    {
        $value = preg_replace(array('#\(#', '#\)#', '#\+#', '#\?#', '#\*#', '#\##', '#\[#', '#\]#', '#\&#', '#\/#', '#\$#', '#\\\\#'), array('\(', '\)', '\+', '\?', '\*', '\#', '\[', '\]', '\&', '\/', '\\\$', '\\\\'), $value);
        return $value;
    }

    $var = "TI - Yeah U Know [OFFCIAL VIDEO] [TAKERS] [w\LYRICS]";

    $var = pregForPreg($var);
    //$var is now:
    //    TI - Yeah U Know \[OFFCIAL VIDEO\] \[TAKERS\] \[w\LYRICS\]
    $var = preg_replace("#" . $var . "#isU", 'test', $var);
    echo $var;
```

And I get an error: *Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \U, or \u at offset 50 in **test.php** on line 13.*

How to make a correct function pregForPreg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want to escape special regex characters. This function already exists and is called [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

---

You get the error, because you don't escape `\` properly:

```
TI - Yeah U Know \[OFFCIAL VIDEO\] \[TAKERS\] \[w\LYRICS\]
//                   this is not escaped   ------^
```

and `\L` has special meaning in Perl regular expression:

> [`\L`  Lowercase until `\E`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html)

but is not supported in PHP's PCRE ([*Perl Differences*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php)):

> The following Perl escape sequences are not supported: `\l, \u, \L, \U`. In fact these are implemented by Perl's general string-handling and are not part of its pattern matching engine.

**Update:**

Obviously, you cannot use the escaped version as value and as pattern, because in the pattern `\[` will be treated as `[` and but in the value `\[` is taken literally. You have to store the escaped string in a new variable:

```
$var = "TI - Yeah U Know [OFFCIAL VIDEO] [TAKERS] [w\LYRICS]";

$escaped = preg_quote($var);
echo $escaped . PHP_EOL;
// prints "TI - Yeah U Know \[OFFCIAL VIDEO\] \[TAKERS\] \[w\\LYRICS\]"
$var = preg_replace('#' . $escaped . '#isU', 'test', $var);
echo $var;
// prints test
```

or easier:

```
$var = preg_replace('#' . preg_quote($var) . '#isU', 'test', $var);
```

Side note: If you really wanted to match `\[` in a string, the regular expression would be `\\\\\[`. You see, it can get quite ugly.

Comment: but my string not replaced with preg_quote

Comment: No, so you'll have to manually escape any \ going in to preg_quote by adding another \ before any already in the string at that point.

Comment: @Isis: I am not sure what you mean. You should use `preg_quote` instead of `pregForPreg`. And your did not specify what you actually want achieve...